# How to make a room completely dark?

Tags: visible-light

Im going to do a dark room retreat for myself where I will stay in a dark room for 40days which has a lot of physical, mental and spiritual benefits.

Now about how to make my room completely dark?
I need to build a ventilation system in order to have a airflow without allowing any light to come in. It's very important that the room is completely dark which raises for me the question how "light resistant" certain material, like carton, dark curtains, tape and other, are?

I was thinking about covering the window with simply a big piece of carton, maybe painted black, and with Duc tape around. And in the other window maybe a black curtain and a whole with a ventilation system wit a tube outside.

Any tips, suggestions are super welcome

Comment: This is also a relevant question for people doing optics experiments who don't want any stray light to affect their setups.

Comment: *I will stay in a dark room for 40days which has a lot of physical, mental and spiritual benefits.*  I would strongly advise getting the view of a mecial professional on that - it's used as a punishment in some places.